# How does an IGBT 120A, 450 watt welding machine inverter mechanism work?

Tags: inverter, high-current, watts

How can "RYU Weld Machine Inverter 120A IGBT 450 watt" be advertised so? Does it really output less than 4V?

How is such a rating determined?

Comment: Yes, probably. That's how welding machines work - low volts, high amps. Inverter means it has a relatively small but still pretty big transformer and a bunch of circuitry.

Comment: Just imagine a forward converter but with thick wires.

Comment: 120A, 4.5V looks legitimate for point welding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some loose specifications from their website (translation into English via Google so E&OE)

[image]

I believe it should be "Input Current: 15.5A".

It's quite unclear where the "450 Watt" comes from given the 3.4kVA input.

As a data point, the detailed manual on my 185A welder  specifies a 50A fuse on a 230VAC supply. Output is specified as 160A at 27V 40% duty cycle. That's 4.3kW @ 40% or average 1.7kW. Input power is specified as 5.2kW (8.7kVA) so better than 80% efficient, as you'd expect for a good quality international brand-name product.

Maybe the actual current capability is something like 85A at 20-24V and the **duty cycle** is 25%. That would work out. They offer other welders with much higher "wattage" ratings. The user manual should be more illuminating and I would suggest not considering purchase without reading the manual.

Comment: I would suggest not considering purchase of something with specs that don't add up.

Comment: @fraxinus In this case they might well add up, but point to a weakness that may or may not be acceptable

Comment: Almost feels like "450W" would be more likely the dissipation than the output, lol. Accounting for duty cycle -- good point. I don't recall anything being rated that way, but maybe that's how they do things over there!

Comment: @TimWilliams Mine is stated to dissipate 300W just sitting there with no output (500VA).  Seems high, I have not measured it.

Answer (score 1):

In simple terms, the IGBT inverter-type arc welder may be likened to a switch mode power supply (SMPS).

Here's the block diagram of a SMPS.

[image]

The compact 50 kHz step-down transformer and filter result in a very compact power supply.

The block diagram of the IGBT inverter-type arc welder is similar to that of the switch mode power supply except that the 50 kHz filter is replaced by a 50 kHz choke.

[image]

Here again, the compact 50 kHz step-down transformer makes the welder quite compact.

3400 VA translates to 450 Watts after the efficiency, power factor and duty cycle are factored in.

Considering 80 % efficiency, 0.3 power factor and 55 % duty cycle,

Welder power = 3400 x 0.80 x 0.30 x 0.55 = 449.

It is presumed that the welder lacks active power factor correction.